# More ready-to-use dialogs for PreferencesFragment

Tags: android, validation, dialog, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

The concept of Android's `PreferencesFragment` is great, but I soon experienced the limitations of this concept, since there are very few dialogs provided. I can't easily achieve user friendly validating dialogs for

- Entering a number in a certain range
- Entering a String in a certain format and length
- Date/Time selection
- Date/Time range selection
- and many more things that need to be validated and require more sophisticated dialog UI

So, my question is: Are there implementations, that provide a large set of nice, customizeable, validating dialogs to be easily integrated in the `PreferencesFragment`?

Comment: No, I don't think so. There might be tutorials or examples for some of the things you listed. (There might even be libraries for specific ones eg. ColorPickerPreference )  Otherwise, it's not so hard to write your own :-)